# my popovercontroller terminating

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uipopovercontroller

I am creating image based application.Now I have allocated  and synthesized pickerviewcontroller in my viewcontroller.m class. 
 as UIImagePickerController *picker. Here I have Give it to the (IBAction).

```
 -(IBAction)selectphoto:(id)sender
 {

    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Then i have set it`s delegate methods.

Now, In my another class named as imagedisplay.m,I have created one Button, at which i want to create popupviewcontroller with my imagepickercontroller images(which is in my viewcontroller class),
Below is my code,

```
-(IBAction)gallery:(id)sender
{

    NSLog(@"pop over done.");

    ViewController *vcntrlr = [[ViewController alloc] init];

    UIPopoverController *popover_=[[UIPopoverController alloc]   initWithContentViewController:vcntrlr.picker];

    [popover_ setDelegate:self];

     [popover_ presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(100, 280,100,100) inView:self.view  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

}
```

I expecting for Displaying popover controller.BUt when i tryng to press Button((IBAction)gallery) my application is terminated and seems below error.

"terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException".
Help me .

Comment: Can you please post the exact text from the exception?

Comment: I did it at bottom part of my que. That`s what i get in console.

Comment: You need to add an exceptions breakpoint. This will stop at the exact line that is crashing so you can see what's going wrong.

Comment: I am stuck at what should i Give to the, "ContentViewController: ". I have also tried to give it "UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary". But got same crash and same error.

Comment: Is your log `NSLog(@"pop over done.");` displayed in your console? If not, issue is somewhere else. You've also written that you've created a file named `viewcontroller.m`. Are `interfaces` and `implementations` written without capital letters?

Comment: @0x7fffffff, i show below in my console, 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:] called when not running under UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad.' ". is that we cant do it on iphone? "

Comment: and when i try to run it through ipad it shows , my app also terminate with '-[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:] must not be called with nil.

Comment: 1th error: You can not use UIPopovercontroller on iPhone (iPad only!). 2nd: `vcntrlr.picker` appears to be nil. Please note the popovercontroller needs an object of type UIViewController, not UIImagePickerController, so you probably need `initWithViewController:vcntrlr`.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that you are not holding any strong reference to the popovercontroller, so it will be released outside the scope of the `-(IBAction)gallery:(id)sender` method. To ensure the popover controller is kept alive after the method has finished, you should keep a strong reference to it.

To do so you can add a property to your class:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController* popoverController;
```

And change your code into:

```
self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:vcntrlr.picker];
[self.popoverController setDelegate:self];
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(100, 280,100,100) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Comment: Too bad.. but why don't you share the exception details as others already mentioned? You clearly got an NSException. The exception details will provide at least a hint on what's causing your issue.

Comment: mention below: " 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:] called when not running under UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad.'
". is that we cvant do it on iphone?

Comment: and when i try to run it through ipad it shows , my app also terminate with '-[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:] must not be called with `nil`.